# Preventing HTML from being modified by external proxies or cellular providers

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web

So we have this website, and as far as I can tell only through the Virgin Mobile 3G cellular network (on an iPhone 4), HTML pages have all of the script and style tags in the head with a src set to a URL inlined within the document.

Merely switching to WiFi or using a device with a different cellular network (like AT&T) and the HTML page will not change.

I can see how this is an optimization to speedup the load time of pages, but one of our scripts will only work if they are not inlined.

Example response not using the Cellular network:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oursite.com/script.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

What we get using the Cellular network:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script style="display: none">
      // The contents of http://oursite.com/script.js (this is bad)
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Is this actually the case or am I just insane? Is there a way to prevent the cellular provider from inlining our script elements?

Comment: You need to focus your question specifically on finding an answer to your programming problem.  That your pages are being modified seems self-evident, and already two answers have been posted to your question that are opinion-based and don't help you solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think I provided at least a _little_ help by directing OP's attention to the carriers for technology to suppress such transformations using http headers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK, sorry. I've reworded it a little bit to ask how to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Cache-Control: no-transform has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Networks, especially mobile networks, do all sorts of things, including in-lining content, compressing (and even resizing) graphics, and [transcoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding). Depending on the carrier, you may (or may not) be able to set some headers in the request and/or the response to suppress some or all of these behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible for internet service providers, web hosts and even virus software to screw with your page. In your case, it is possible that the mobile provider is doing it - or the browser is using a proxy that optimises pages.

What code are you running that can't handle being in-lined? Maybe it could be tweaked to allow it to work either way?

Comment: It's a GWT module. We have the module being served from a CloudFront CDN with the document's location being from our nginx front end. The GWT module needs to know that it's location is from the CloudFront CDN and not from the nginx front end. If the script is inlined, it will try to get the rest of the permutation JavaScripts from the wrong URL and 404.